# firefox opera custom search engine and mod_rewrite sites

Tags: firefox, search-engine, opera, usability, backreference

In firefox and opera one can create a custom search engine but it passes along the search as a standard get or post variable. Is there anyway to embed that search term in the url for sites that use pretty urls.

Example
I search github 1411 and it sends me to github.com/myusername/myproject/ticket-1411

or even better two parameters
I search github compare 1411 sends me to github.com/myusername/myproject/compare/ticket-1411

Answer (score 1):

Use the github domain as the search URL and %s to substitute the number at the end:

```
http://www.github.com/myusername/myproject/ticket-%s
```

Search for `1411` to test the custom search.